# Property 'saveButton' not found on object of type 'AddToDoItemViewController'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong here. I am working through a tutorial. I have double checked my typing. I have even copied and pasted the code but I am still getting this error.

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (IBAction)textField:(id)sender {
}
 - (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
    self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
    self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
}
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;

@end
```

Comment: That did in fact solve my problem. Now for some reason out of nowhere though XCode is freaking out.

https://www.evernote.com/l/AJiFB9OusMhCkZTiHyPl9oE3Cn_q0F4zGPk

Please take a look at the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted here, your class does not have a property called `saveButton`. It has a method called `saveButton:`. So the error message appears to be correct.

Comment: If you want, you can see my source here: https://bitbucket.org/mlavender/to-do-app Im new to programming and honestly, I probably need to start at learning C.